# GtkEntry with GtkEntryCompletion

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

I'm looking for a guide for how to hook up a GtkEntry widget with a GtkEntryCompletion object. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but I have the impression that when hooked up properly, I should be seeing suggestions from the GtkEntryCompletion object as I type in the GtkEntry box, but so far that is not happening.

I'm using Gtk3 and also Glade 3.22. In my GtkEntry widget, in the General properties, in "Completion" I have my GtkEntryCompletion object selected. In My GtkEntryCompletion object general properties, in "Completion Model," I have my GtkTreeStore model selected. When I run the program, I have the model items being displayed in a GtkTreeView. When I begin to type in my GtkEntry widget, there doesn't seem to be any kind of interactive-ness happening. Do I need to do all of that manually (i.e. capturing user input, searching the model, and doing my own thing with suggestions)?

Answer (score 0):

In GtkEntryCompletion "General" properties, I had to specify the "Text Column" field, to specify which field in the GtkTreeStore to match against. I guess my next question will be how to get this to work against multiple fields (i.e. first / or last name).